# Do containers have a small fixed margin

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Keeping Containers Continuously has some margin between them and why aren't they in same color

This the row of 411 containers

```
   Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < 411; ++i)
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                width: 1,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
          ],
        ),
```

[image]

Is this normal in flutter or should anything be changed ?

Comment: Is this normal in flutter? as everything is same color and should be have same color but it looks like some are orange

Comment: it has nothing to do with `Container` - most likely one logical pixel is not equal to one physical pixel on your device and thats why you see such artifacts

Comment: The phone is said to be 1080x1920, when running mediaquery to find width it is saying 411.42857142857144 as width. Why does this happen

Comment: what's the value of `devicePixelRatio`? this value tells how many physical pixels are drawn when you draw one logical pixel (like your container with `width: 1`)

Comment: pixel ratio is 2.625, im using google pixel 2. Sorry to disturb you, but how does this help

Comment: it helps in that if you draw one logical pixel then 2.625 physical pixels are drawn: first 2 pixels are drawn in pure red and the third pixel is drawn in something that is similar to pure red - thats why you see such things, the question is what actually do you want to achieve with those 411 one pixel wide containers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232442/discussion-between-balu-k-and-pskink).

Comment: Can you try using expanded ?

Comment: yes i did, and nothing changed.